# How does it calculate a checksum?

Tags: frida, ghidra

in Ghidra I found a function that calculates a checksum and checks it against a checksum in a protobuf I'm stuck in this function for days and I tried using frida to get the ret value
but it doesn't return. I know it's void but on another function that called this calculateBackupChecksum it does return a value

```
    this_00 = (GameController *)ei::Backup::Backup(aBSta ck_4d8,(Backup *)param_1);
    lVar44 = calculateBackupChecksum(this_00,(Backup)t his_00);
    lVar8 = *(longlong *)(param_1 + 0x88);
    ei::Backup::~Backup(aBStack_4d8);
    if (lVar44 != lVar8) {
      // Checksum invalid ret do return 
    }
```

```
void __thiscall GameController::calculateBackupChecksum (GameController *this,Backup param_1)

{
  int iVar1;
  int iVar2;
  uint uVar3;
  uint uVar4;
  uint uVar5;
  undefined4 extraout_r1;
  uint uVar6;
  undefined4 uVar7;
  uint uVar8;
  int iVar9;
  undefined4 uVar10;
  uint uVar11;
  undefined4 uVar12;
  undefined4 uVar13;
  double dVar14;
  double dVar15;
  undefined4 in_stack_fffffd68;
  undefined4 in_stack_fffffd6c;
  uint local_270;
  Backup aBStack_268 [76];
  Backup_Simulation *local_21c;
  Backup_Simulation **local_218;
  int local_214;
  Backup aBStack_1d0 [76];
  Backup_Simulation *local_184;
  Backup_Simulation **local_180;
  int local_17c;
  Backup_Simulation aBStack_138 [64];
  uint local_f8;
  int iStack_f4;
  int local_28;
  
  local_28 = __stack_chk_guard;
  iVar9 = *(int *)(param_1 + 0x44);
  if (iVar9 == 0) {
    dVar14 = *(double *)(*(int *)(DAT_00cd9bf0 + 0x44) + 0 x70);
    if (dVar14 != 0.0 && dVar14 < 0.0 == NAN(dVar14)) goto  LAB_007196be;
  }
  else {
    dVar14 = *(double *)(iVar9 + 0x70);
    if (dVar14 != 0.0 && dVar14 < 0.0 == NAN(dVar14)) {
LAB_007196be:
      iVar1 = iVar9;
      if (iVar9 == 0) {
        iVar1 = *(int *)(DAT_00cd9bf0 + 0x44);
      }
      uVar7 = (undefined4)*(undefined8 *)(iVar1 + 0x70);
      log10((double)CONCAT44(in_stack_fffffd6c,in_stack_ff fffd68));
      dVar15 = (double)CONCAT44(extraout_r1,uVar7);
      dVar14 = 0.0;
      if (dVar15 != 0.0 && dVar15 < 0.0 == NAN(dVar15)) {
        dVar14 = dVar15;
      }
      local_270 = (uint)(longlong)(dVar14 * 100.0);
      goto joined_r0x0071971c;
    }
  }
  local_270 = 0;
joined_r0x0071971c:
  if (iVar9 == 0) {
    iVar9 = *(int *)(DAT_00cd9bf0 + 0x44);
  }
  uVar7 = *(undefined4 *)(iVar9 + 0x18);
  uVar10 = *(undefined4 *)(iVar9 + 0x1c);
  uVar13 = *(undefined4 *)(iVar9 + 0x30);
  uVar12 = *(undefined4 *)(iVar9 + 0x34);
  ei::Backup::Backup(aBStack_1d0,(Backup *)param_1);
  if (local_17c < 1) {
    if (local_184 == (Backup_Simulation *)0x0) {
      local_184 = *(Backup_Simulation **)(DAT_00cd9bf0 +  0x4c);
    }
    ei::Backup_Simulation::Backup_Simulation(aBStack_13 8,local_184);
  }
  else {
    ei::Backup_Simulation::Backup_Simulation(aBStack_13 8,*local_180);
  }
  iVar9 = *(int *)(param_1 + 0x60);
  if (iVar9 == 0) {
    iVar9 = *(int *)(DAT_00cd9bf0 + 0x60);
  }
  ei::Backup_Simulation::~Backup_Simulation(aBStack_13 8);
  ei::Backup::~Backup(aBStack_1d0);
  iVar9 = *(int *)(param_1 + 0x44);
  if (iVar9 == 0) {
    iVar9 = *(int *)(DAT_00cd9bf0 + 0x44);
  }
  uVar8 = *(uint *)(iVar9 + 0x18);
  iVar1 = *(int *)(iVar9 + 0x1c);
  uVar11 = *(uint *)(iVar9 + 0x30);
  iVar9 = *(int *)(iVar9 + 0x34);
  ei::Backup::Backup(aBStack_268,(Backup *)param_1);
  if (local_214 < 1) {
    if (local_21c == (Backup_Simulation *)0x0) {
      local_21c = *(Backup_Simulation **)(DAT_00cd9bf0 +  0x4c);
    }
    ei::Backup_Simulation::Backup_Simulation(aBStack_13 8,local_21c);
  }
  else {
    ei::Backup_Simulation::Backup_Simulation(aBStack_13 8,*local_218);
  }
  iVar2 = *(int *)(param_1 + 0x60);
  if (iVar2 == 0) {
    iVar2 = *(int *)(DAT_00cd9bf0 + 0x60);
  }
  uVar6 = *(uint *)(iVar2 + 0x34);
  ei::Backup_Simulation::~Backup_Simulation(aBStack_13 8);
  ei::Backup::~Backup(aBStack_268);
  uVar3 = uVar8 + local_270;
  uVar4 = uVar3 + uVar11;
  uVar5 = uVar4 + local_f8;
  if (__stack_chk_guard != local_28) {
                    /* WARNING: Subroutine does not return */
    __stack_chk_fail(uVar5 + uVar6,
                     iVar1 + ((int)local_270 >> 0x1f) + (uint)CARR Y4(uVar8,local_270) + iVar9 +
                     (uint)CARRY4(uVar3,uVar11) + iStack_f4 + (ui nt)CARRY4(uVar4,local_f8) +
                     ((int)uVar6 >> 0x1f) + (uint)CARRY4(uVar5,uV ar6));
  }
  return;
}
```

Comment: Functions don't need to have a return value, there are a lot of different methods to save a result value (out parameters, a struct parameter pointer, a field of an object,... ) Also keep in mind that decompiler can always fail. So make yourself familiar with the assembler code and check if it really fits to the decompiled code or if parts are missing.